# Handle file chunks from Dropzone in Laravel

Tags: image, video, chunks, laravel-7, dropzone

I tried to use [pionl/laravel-chunk-upload](https://github.com/pionl/laravel-chunk-upload) but it doesn't work with Laravel 7. I also tried to combine the chunks like the following.

```php
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    // open the chunk file
    $file = fopen($chunk->getRealPath(), 'rb');
    // read the data & store it in a variable (each chunk is 20mb)
    $buff = fread($file, 2097152);
    fclose($file);
    // open the output file
    $total = fopen($out, 'ab');
    // write the data in it
    fwrite($total, $buff);
    fclose($total);
}
```

It combines the chunks into 1 file with the original size but it doesn't work, and it loses the video or image information.

Comment: Better using this package https://github.com/pionl/laravel-chunk-upload-example

Comment: thx for sending that, but I managed to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of storing the data of the chunk file & writing it to the file, I used the PHP function `file_get_contents($chunk_path)` to get the chunk data.

```
$file = fopen($temp_file_path, 'w');

for ($i = 0; $i < $total_chunks; $i++) {
    $chunk_path = "{$temp_dir}/{$file_name}.part{$i}";
    
    if (!is_file($part_path)) {
        File::deleteDirectory($temp_dir);
        abort(404);
    }

    fwrite($file, file_get_contents($chunk_path));

}

fclose($file);
```